# Design safe area / top and bottom bars height through different systems and browsers

Tags: website-design, web-safe

When designing RWD how do You consider design safe area? For example in 1920x1080, do You design for 1080 or You shrink it? If shrink, how much, considering Windows and Mac and also different browsers? What's the safe height that takes in consideration every medium out there? We measured 980-970px for Windows but it's 948-900px for OS X - what do You think?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mobile first**

As of 2013 more people view web sites on mobile devices than on desktops. You should be *far more* concerned about how your site appears on a phone than on a monitor.

That being posted, you can check **browser statistics** to determine some general information.

For example, checking https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp will show that in Jan 2017 there were still a fair amount of users with a max window height of 768px.

[image]

900px would be obviously too much to show everything. Now, take W3Schools **with a grain of salt**. They are often incorrect on matters. They are **not** associated with the W3C.

There are other sites as well.

https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php shows reportedly a more recent statistic of Nov 2017:

[image]

How absolutely accurate these statistics are for **your site** is a mystery. Many hosting packages have a statistics package such as AWStats or you may even be using Google Analytics. These would give a more accurate understanding of those using *your* site. The only clear factor is designing for mobile screens is far more important than designing for a desktop screen.

Personally... for a web site on desktop, I use 600px max height as the "above the fold" area. And while responsiveness will decrease the width of a page, sticking to 600px height works well for mobile screens as well.

Comment: Thanks for such thorough explanation but unfortunately that wasn't my point at all. We know to design mobile-first and we know the statistics, also we know the most common resolutions and know about W3C being unreliable. The question was about SAFE AREA - from UX point of view what safe area You use when designing websites? Which means, what height of Windows'/Mac's top and bottom bars You count?

Comment: Also - we know about RWD being RESPONSIVE and we know about 100% VH and other algorithms - still, that's not the point.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to clarify the question as opposed to down voting?

Comment: I do not see how *"I use 600px max height as the "above the fold" area"* does NOT answer the question as it's presented.

Comment: Ok, got it. I understand designing for 600px for laptop's "above the fold" but what about fullHD, 2K and 5K? Wouldn't it be too much? I doubt there's any system out there that uses such big nav/adress/menu bars.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean I use 600px as a *navigation* height. That would be ridiculous in 99% of use cases. I keep navigation as minimal as feasible.  I ensure that anything I need the reader to see immediately is in the top 600px of every page.  I can add additional "imperatives" below it which will show to users on larger screens.  I **really** think you need to edit your question and *explain a great deal more* what you are trying to ask, because after these comments, I'm completely unclear as to what you *think* you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for that misunderstanding @Scott. Maybe I should name it "design safe area". Uploaded a picture. By web safe area I mean the green zone which determines how we design e.g. fixed top or bottom website nav bars (their height) or other elements that we want to be seen without folding. It's mostly for developing purposes since not every dev is clever enough to guess that if there's a bottom fixed nav in 1920x1080 window, it should actually be fixed to the bottom of window, not whole screen... *facepalm*

Comment: Okay.. yes, that's often called the area "above the fold" (old newspaper term). And I use a max of 600px height. Although screens and browsers vary, the will ALL show 600px. Some may show 640, some may show 760... 900.. etc. But you can only really ensure 99% of  viewers will see 600PX. Even on mobile - while narrower, 600px is a common height for devices.

Comment: Also there are a number of smaller laptops using things like 440x768px resolutions...  screens may be at 768px height.. add the browser frame etc.. and 600 px is still safe.

Comment: thanks for staying with me on this :) Merry Christmas, Scott!